# Initialization of memory allocated with stackalloc

Tags: c#, unsafe, stackalloc

If I'm allocating memory with `stackalloc` in *C#*, **is that memory initialized *(with `0`)*?**
The documentation doesn't speak of that and only tells that the correct amount is reserved.

In my tests such memory defaulted to `0`, but that doesn't mean it's guaranteed though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the spec:

> **18.8 Stack allocation**
>
> The content of the newly allocated memory is undefined.

Comment: Now that the stackalloc can be used in "safe" context with Span<T>, does this still hold true?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the spec says it is undefined, but the compiler emits `localloc` CIL intruction for `stackalloc`. And this is what ECMA Specs says about `localloc`:

> The localloc instruction allocates size (type native unsigned int)
>   bytes from the local dynamic memory pool and returns the address (a
>   managed pointer, type &) of the first allocated byte. The block of
>   memory returned is initialized to 0 only if the initialize flag on the
>   method is true (see Partition I). The area of memory is newly
>   allocated. When the current method returns the local memory pool is
>   available for reuse.

The initialize flag, also known as `localsinit` flag, is emitted for every method by the compiler because it is required for verifiable code.

Please look at [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1279) on coreclr asking to stop zeroing memory on stackalloc. At the end of the issue jkotas says:

> The current plan is:
>
> C# will keep zero initializing by default. Changing the default would
>   be too breaking. We have a set of issues opened to make the zero
>   initialization done by the JIT more efficient or reduce need for it
>   (#13827, #13823, #13825) Folks who really want to get the last bit of
>   performance by avoiding zero initialization can use custom ILLinker
>   step (mono/linker#159) when they know what they are doing. We do this
>   for CoreLib today (via VM hack, but we should switch to the ILLinker),
>   and we plan to experiment with this in CoreFX (dotnet/corefx#25956).
>   Based on the results of these experiments, we may consider introducing
>   a more streamlined way to do this in future. @ahsonkhan You should
>   consider experimenting with it in CoreFXLab as well if you believe
>   that it would help.

And see this [csharplang](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1738) proposal

So the conclusion is: **the memory is initialized to zero in practice**

However there is a bug/feature in the compiler that prevents from emiting `localsinit` flag. Unsafe methods that don't declare other variables and use the stack allocated variable only to passing it to other method, don't get marked with the `localsinit` flag.

Here is an example of such bug/feature:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace InformalTests
{

    class Program
    {
        const int n = 100_000_000;

        static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i =0; i < n; i++)
            {
                ThisMethodDoes_NOT_InitializeStackAllocatedMemory();
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"NOT INITIALIZED elapsed time {watch.Elapsed}");

            watch.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                ThisMethodInitializeStackAllocatedMemory();
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"INITIALIZED Elapsed time {watch.Elapsed}");
        }


        private static unsafe string ThisMethodDoes_NOT_InitializeStackAllocatedMemory()
        {
            // avoid declaring other local vars, or doing work with stackalloc
            // to prevent the .locals init cil flag , see: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1279
            char* pointer = stackalloc char[256];
            return CreateString(pointer, 256);
        }

        private static unsafe string ThisMethodInitializeStackAllocatedMemory()
        {
            //Declaring a variable other than the stackallocated, causes
            //compiler to emit .locals int cil flag, so it's slower
            int i = 256;
            char* pointer = stackalloc char[256];
            return CreateString(pointer, i);
        }

        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        private static unsafe string CreateString(char* pointer, int length)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

The **not initialized** method is five times faster than the **initialized** one.